# App is not installed after changed applicationId

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to Android development.

I finally finished up my first android application and
tried to upload on google play.
then I found out I can't use com."example" package name for uploading.
so I already changed all my package name to com."◯◯◯" and it worked fine.

but once I changed applicationId in gradle app file which corresponds to the package name, my app is not installed any more...
there's no error message in android studio and seems to fine.

I did clean and rebuild, invalidate caches/restart, uninstall existing app on my device, etc..but any of them not working.

I couldn't find any solution for it. please help me to fix this problem.

thank you

---update. case solved---

It was because if you change the applicationId, the installed app is brand new one(doesn't have any data in the database). so the problem was null variable which I didn't make it nullable.

thank you for your help.

Comment: You changed package name to "com.◯◯◯", then what your gradle package says pakcage name is? - package="com.myapplication.lifelogapp" . 
Fix it. What you mean by not installed anymore?

Comment: I changed package name "example" to "myapplication" which is second top of the directory.
 I have build.gradle (Module: LifelogApp.app) and build.gradle(Project: Lifelog App)

Comment: "not installed anymore" means  build operation works fine but app is not installed on my device

Comment: change to package ="com.myapplication" in gradle also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

change all place-name where package name use it then try

Comment: It's already changed to new name as far as I can check...